# CSS - position: absolute not working to place div above all other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Javascript (more specifically the VueJS framework) to build a page called mainTextEditor which has a text field and a 'popup' made using a div with a v-if which shows the div when the condition met is true.

It may be important to note that this is a component within another component like so (Inserted using main-text-editor):

```
<template>
    <v-card flat>
        <div class="background-colour-grey form-title temp-build-ellipse temp-build-overflow d-flex">
            <v-card-title class="form-title pl-0 pr-1">{{ itemHere.name }}</v-card-title>
        </div>
        <v-card-actions>
            <div
                class="mt-0 pa-0"
            >
               // HERE IS WHERE THE COMPONENT IS INSERTED
               <main-text-editor
                   class="mt-0 pt-0 background-colour-grey"
               />
            </div>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

This is the code used to generate the mainTextEditor text field and popup above:

```
<template>
    <div class="my-auto width-100" style="position: relative !important;">
        <v-card flat>
            <v-text-field :editor="editor"/>
        </v-card>
        <div class="formula-options" v-if="editorContentIsUsingFormulas">
            <v-list class="pt-0 pb-0" dense v-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.id" >
                <v-list-item class="d-flex">
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>{{ item.structure }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

editorContentIsUsingFormulas is true when the text field is clicked

CSS styles used above:

```
.formula-options {
    z-index: 2 !important;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30vw;
    max-height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute !important;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.temp-build-ellipse {
    max-height: 39.98px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.temp-build-overflow {
    height: 39.98px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

The issue is that although the div has been styled to show position: absolute, if the text field in question is at the bottom of the page then it creates whitespace that goes beyond the full 100vh of the entire page.

Here is what it looks like in the middle of the page:

[image]

Here is what it looks like at the bottom (Please note that the purple represents the full page):

[image]

Here is what a text field looks like at the side of the page (note that the white part on the right hand side is the end of the page and I can no longer see the right hand side of the div):

[image]

I am assuming that because the div is towards the bottom of the  tag, it is positioned at the bottom of the text field. However, I am under the impression that position: absolute should fix it, though this doesn't seem to be the case. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: you need to set WHERE you want it absolutely positioned with some of top/left/bottom/right as appropriate (not all required, just enough to position it where you want it)

Comment: Well, position absolute just positions the element relative to it's closest parent with a position set.( eg relative ) . So, using position absolute doesn't mean the element will be bound to the viewport width/height. You need to specify the width, height, XY position or the absolute positioned element

Comment: @Bravo I set for example top: 50px etc. and it unfortunately didn't prevent it from going over the page. The issue is that even if I define such properties it doesn't prevent it from showing the whitespace at the bottom if I have the text-field at the bottom of the page

Comment: @MihaiT I've set the width and height relative to the viewport in the example, can I ask what you mean by XY position? What property specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. interesting. Can you just try min-height: 100vh? Sorry If I misunderstand the question.

Comment: Dont post questions as answers. Use the comment section.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29852941)